# Recursively add consecutive vector values in R

Tags: r, recursion, vector, addition

Assume I have a vector containing the following values:

```
foo <- c(1:5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there a function or otherwise quick way to get each value of `foo` to add recursively to the numbers before it?

Desired Result is a vector containing these added values:

```
1 3 6 10 15
```

- `foo[1]` is `1`, `foo[1] + foo[2]` is `1 + 2` = `3`, `foo[1] + foo[2] + foo[3]` is `1 + 2 + 3` = `6`, etc.

**My attempt:**

I came up with:

```
vapply(1:length(foo), function(x) sum(foo[1]:foo[x]),integer(1))
```

But I'm hoping there is a simpler way to do this...

Comment: Check out `cumsum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `cumsum` does exactly that:

```
cumsum(foo)
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15
```

Another handy and closely related function is `cumprod(x)` for cumulative products. See `?cumsum`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! Out of curiosity, how does `cumsum` work? I looked [here](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/base/man/cumsum.Rd), but the linked description doesn't include the underlying *functional* code (i.e., what the function is *actually doing*)

Comment: @theforestecologist, that's because *.Rd are just documentation files. See the first function in https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/cum.c

Comment: And the downvote is for...?